# How can I show closest date-to-happen posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, post, activeadmin

I am building a site that displays a weekly resume of what will be going on.
My problem is: an admin can place a post two months from now, how can I restrict those posts from showing up until the week it would actually happen?

Comment: Maybe you would show to us some code...

Answer (score 1):

Use a scope or two:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :future, lambda { where('ends_at > ?', Time.zone.now') }
  scope :up_to, lambda { |time| where('starts_at < ?', time) }
end

@coming_up_posts = Post.future.up_to(7.days.from_now)
```

Comment: This is a better example for Events but the concept still applies.

Comment: tyvm bro! this is a solution to my problem!